# How to get/set user agent on iOS 4.x?

Tags: iphone, user-agent

I have a webview app tool, which essentially consists of the webview and two buttons on a toolbar.  One button to view the source of the page, and another button to view/change the current User Agent.

I have both functions working on iOS 5 (view source, and change User Agent), but I cant seem to grab the User Agent in iOS 4.x.

I'm using the following now:

```
userAgentViewController.UAText = [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"navigator.userAgent"];
```

This works in iOS5, but in iOS 4.x, it doesnt return anything.  Is there a way to achieve the same functionality in iOS 4.x?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to get the useragent, check the HTTP header in the NSURLRequest of your response.
You can retreive this one in the *webViewDidFinishLoad* delegate method.

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    NSLog(@"%@", [[webView request] valueForHTTPHeaderField: @"User-Agent"]);
}
```

to set it, you have to custom an NSMutableURLRequest and give it to your webView

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"yourwebsite.com"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:USERAGENT_STRING forHTTPHeaderField: @"User-Agent"];
[webView loadRequest:request];
[request release];
```

and that's it !

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the AppDelegate.m

```
+ (void)initialize 

{

    // Set user agent (the only problem is that we can’t modify the User-Agent later in the program)

    // iOS 5.1

    NSDictionary *dictionnary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@”Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 5_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1 Mobile/9B176 Safari/7534.48.3”, @”UserAgent”, nil];


    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:dictionnary];

}
```

Comment: similarly in app delegate, can i get the current user agent?